# retrieve information from activities in processMapR

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem with "ProcessmapR" . 
Take the eventlog "patients" from package "eventdataR" , as an example .
We can get a plot from Business Process via "process_map(patients)".
Now I want to find out which patient-ID has passed through a node just by selecting the node in "Viewer" .
How can I do it ?

```
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)

process_map(patients)
```

[click here to see the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNQx2.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The graph generated by process_map is static and you can't get much information from it;
There are ways to add any tooltip that you want on any of the nodes of the graph, though:
You need to do the process_map with render=FALSE option and save it to a variable, and then you can change it as you wish; for instance:

```
gr <- process_map(patients, render=FALSE)
gr$nodes_df$tooltip[1] <- "Just a test!"
render_graph(gr)
```

The code segment above is just for illustration, and by no means is supposed to be considered as a good way of doing this job.